# How can i sort my list of names alphabetically?

Tags: c#

I would like to know, how can i sort the names and surenames alphabetically in my list.

I'm not sure, but i googled and i'm guessing it only sort's by the name.

```
    public void FilterParticipants(List<string> players, PlayerContainer allPlayers)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < allPlayers.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!players.Contains(allPlayers.FindName(i) + " " + allPlayers.FindSurname(i)))
            {
                players.Add(allPlayers.FindName(i) + " " + allPlayers.FindSurname(i));
            }
        }
        players.Sort();
    }
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: The short answer is that you must have a `List<Player>` rather than `List<string>`. Then you will do something like `var players = playerList.OrderBy(z -> z.FirstName).ThenBy(z => z.Surname).Select(z => z.FirstName + " " + z.Surname).ToList();` to convert that to a `List<string>` in the order that you want it.

Comment: it's usually bad form to modify inputs in a method without requiring the ref keyword.

Comment: @FelixCastor Is sorting the inputs a bad idea? Yes, yes it is. But adding `ref` would make it even **more** confusing, since it would imply that the called code isn't sorting the data in place but is instead assigning a new array to it - which it isn't.

Comment: @mjwills fair point.

Comment: For a quick, easy solution, go with @mjwills answer. If you find that you will need to frequently sort Player objects and would like to do so without typing out the LINQ expressions each time, implement IComparable. Then you can just call playerList.Sort(). There is also some performance benefits to this approach since LINQ will construct a new IEnumerable vs sorting the existing list.

Comment: How did you go trying my suggestion @Dom?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sort your player names by Surname and then Name and cannot change your design to have a `List<Player>` passed in, then here's one solution.

Note there's a slight design change, as it's usually better to return a new list rather than modifying the input list. Also, the method name is a little misleading. "Filter" implies that you're *reducing* the set of items based on some criteria, but in this case we're *adding* items if they don't exist, so I renamed it to `GetCombinedParticipants`.

Given that, here's one way you could implement it. Note that this design uses `Substring` to find the last space in the name, which is used as a delimeter between the first name and the last name (which therefore assumes that there are no spaces in the last name). If there are, then I don't know how you could possibly identify them from a `List<string>`, which is another good reason to create a `Player` class with separate `FirstName` and `Surname` poperties...

```
public List<string> GetCombinedParticipants(List<string> players, 
    PlayerContainer allPlayers)
{
    // Make a copy of the input list
    var results = players.ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < allPlayers.Count; i++)
    {
        var fullName = $"{allPlayers.FindName(i)} {allPlayers.FindSurname(i)}";

        if (!results.Contains(fullName)) results.Add(fullName);
    }

    // Order by last name, then by first name
    return results
        .OrderBy(name => name.Substring(name.LastIndexOf(" ") + 1)) 
        .ThenBy(name => name.Substring(0, name.LastIndexOf(" ")))
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: This relies on people having no spaces in their first or surname.

Comment: @mjwills Isn't that a fair assumption? Unless I am seriously culture blind here

Comment: @Cubemaster https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-personal-names "because some people consider a space-separated sequence of characters to be a single name, eg. Rose Marie." https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/05/25/multipart-names/ could be even worse for surnames.

Comment: I like that you are trying to anticipate their needs, and yet hesitant to like a solution that doesn't properly structure the data. For instance: what if two players share a name? How will you differentiate the surname? It looks like you are relying upon the list of player names being synchronized with the index that they appear in the PlayerContainer, but that doesn't sound like a sound solution to me. Since this is supposed to serve as a filter, it would be bad to assume that the indeces of the player names you are filtering by correspond with the player indeces in the larger PlayerContainer

Comment: Well would you look at that. There's a standard for this stuff.

Comment: @mjwills Great point. I updated the answer to call that out, and also updated the code to use the last space as a delimiter. Dealing with a `List<string>` kind of ties our hands on this one...we have to make some assumption which will invariably prove wrong at some point.

Comment: @Cubemaster David Lloyd George is a well-known example of a famous person with a space in his surname. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Lloyd_George

Comment: @RyanPierceWilliams Fair point, this is still unstructured data based on the OP's original `PlayerContainer` class (which appears to have an internal list or two that are used to store names). If two players share a name, they will appear right next to each other (it's just a `List<string>` after all). But the code does not do any filtering, so I'm not sure I understand your point about that.

Comment: @RufusL The function in the OP is titled FilterParticipants. Of course, now that I look at it closer the function isn't actually filtering but expanding the list of players! Ha! The OPs code needs to be torched with fire until dead. The way the OPs code is designed is just fundamentally unsound, so anything that builds off of it will also be unsound. But I still give you props for trying :)